# Transaction Reverting when trying to deploy s new smart contract from inside another smart contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I made a smart contract that has a method and when this method is called it creates a new contract passing in the contract constructor arguments

```
contract Pool{

 Constructor(address adA,address adB,uint u1,uint u2){
_;//the rest of the code 
  }
}


contract swap{
  Function createPool(
  address _ad1,
  address _ad2,
  uint u1,
  uint u2)external{
  
  Pool newPool =new Pool(_ad1,_ad2,u1,u2)
  }
}
```

When I run this in remix I get a revert error and remix doesn't make the reason for this error very clear

Except for just saying "EVM revert"

Comment: So  for better context ,I get a revert error when I try to run the createPool function in the swap contract